# Angular 4 routing params captured as undefined

Tags: angular, parameters, router

I'm new at Angular. I'm attempting to edit an item at localhost:4200/edit/:id but I can't capture the :id param to fetch the corresponding number from it (it is supposed to be something like localhost:4200/edit/7, for example). When I output the params.id to console, it always shows "undefined".

My app.module.ts

```
...
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

const routes = [
{ path: '', component: NavigateComponent },
{ path: 'field', component: FieldComponent },
{ path: 'book', component: MaterialFullComponent, children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: ':id_book', component: MaterialFullComponent }
] },
{ path: 'edit', component: MaterialEditComponent, children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'new', component: MaterialEditComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: MaterialEditComponent }
] },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/'}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppLoginComponent,
    NavigateComponent,
    MaterialEditComponent,
    MaterialFullComponent,
    FieldComponent,
    MaterialComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [
    MarcService,
    BookService,
    BookDetailService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

My MaterialEditComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { BookService } from '../book.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-material-edit',
  templateUrl: './material-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./material-edit.component.css']
})

export class MaterialEditComponent implements OnInit {
  activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;  
  bookService: BookService;
  selectedBook = {  id_book: null, 
                numero_ejemplares: null, 
                autor: '', 
                titulo: '',
                editorial: '',
                fecha_publicacion: '',
                portada: ''
  };

  constructor(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, bookService: BookService) {
    this.activatedRoute = activatedRoute;
    this.bookService = bookService;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        console.log(params.id);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try accessing the id using ['id']  ie console.log(params['id']);

Comment: Tried it, still nothing.

Comment: I don't think it's helping to define component and children on the same route. Also note you can use parameter properties to simplify your definition, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: can you create a plunker demo for your issue , that can give a better idea of the problem

Answer (score 10):

According to the official [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/router), the use of `params` is discouraged. Instead, the suggestion is to use [`paramMap`](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) instead:

> Two older properties are still available. They are less capable than their replacements, discouraged, and may be deprecated in a future Angular version.
>
> params — An Observable that contains the required and optional parameters specific to the route. Use paramMap instead.
>
> queryParams — An Observable that contains the query parameters available to all routes. Use queryParamMap instead.

To use `paramMap`, replace your `ngOnInit` with the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params.get('id'));
  });
}
```

I realise this isn't a direct fix for your issue, but I'm interested to see if it works for you. I would've written this as a comment but it would've been hard to read.

Comment: still getting undefined.  Most docs I see were forcing me to use routerLink but I know we can capture the /:id onInit.  oh well , keep searching

Answer (score 3):

Got what was wrong, or at least got it to work.

Changed my routing definitions to:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavigateComponent },
  { path: 'field', component: FieldComponent },
  { path: 'book/:id_book', component: MaterialEditComponent },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: MaterialEditComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/'}
];
```

Apparently, using 'children' does it not good.